# how can I make an action onchange in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to pass `collection_select` a value with the `link_to_remote` method. When I did this, I got an internal server error. I am using Rails 2.3.8. My code:

```
 <%= collection_select("event", "trainer_id", @trainers , :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Select a Trainer'}, {:onchange=> "#{link_to_remote(:url => {:controller => 'events', :action => 'find_new' }, :with=>"'trainer_id='+value")}"}) %>
```

**Added**

This my controller code:

```
def find_new
@trainers= Trainer.all
if ["0"].include?(params[:trainer_id])
    render :partial=>'events/me'
    else
    render :partial=> 'events/something'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onchange` will expect javascript, you're providing an HTML `a` element with your `link_to_remote`.

I'm guessing you'd want to redirect the user to the page you selected?

```
<%= collection_select("event", "trainer_id", @trainers , :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Select a Trainer'}, {:onchange=> "redirectToTrainer(this.value)"}) %>

<%= javascript_tag do %>
  function redirectToTrainer(trainerId){
     window.location = "<%= url_for(:controller => 'events', :action => 'find_new') %>?" + trainerId;
  } 
<% end %>
```

There are cleaner ways to do this, Unobtrusive Javascript for one, but I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I did this ... but still Iam getting the error. I add my controller code above. why did I get this error?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error please?  Is there possibly a syntax error in your collection_select?  Also, what are you trying to achieve exactly in the find_new? I'd recommend against getting the whole collection of Trainers if you're just trying to figure out if it's one?

Comment: I did not get any stack trace... I got this error from firebug. I did this code inside pop_up box. It was using jQuery. I want to get all trainers...

Comment: If you go to your console, you should see a stack trace if you're getting a 500 error from the browser.